# auto collapsing flex container with children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to have a flex container with 2 children with the following behavior:

- container takes up 100% width
- children both take up 50 % width of container
- children shrink with viewport until parent reaches some minimum width.
- After reaching the minimum width, the children get stacked vertically and continue to shrink in proportion to the parent container.

What would be the css to accomplish this?

Comment: Please share some of the code you have come up with. HTML, CSS.

Comment: Please share your fiddle

Comment: SO is not a coding service, we don't ask for free coding here

Comment: The commenters are right. I should have included my non-working code. My appologies.

Comment: Never too late to add the code.

Answer (score -2):

Here is solution

https://codepen.io/parthjasani/pen/gvaOBR

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background:#000;
  padding:10px;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside { flex: 1 auto; }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am the downvoter because the OP provided 0 effort and ask for free code which is clearly off topic in SO. Answering such question will simply encourage people to always ask them again and again. So better flag the question or comment it to improve it. So I downvote this to discourage people from answering such questions

Comment: Thank you very much Parth. I should have added my own code which did not do what was intended.